# Get tp.address_from and tp.address_to from travel_point table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I'm building a view for get `tp.address_from` and `tp.address_to` but I can't get this works. This is the query I'm working on:

```
SELECT
    `tp`.`address_from` AS `address_from`,
    `tp`.`address_to` AS `address_to`,
    `bk`.`firstname` AS `firstname`
FROM
    (
        `book` `bk`
        LEFT JOIN `travel_point` `tp` ON(
            (
                (`bk`.`tp_from` = `tp`.`id`)
                AND(`bk`.`tp_to` = `tp`.`id`)
            )
        )
    )
```

But it's not working since I get always a set of empty results as picture below shows:

[image]

Between `book` and `travel_point` tables exists the same relation twice: `tp_from` is a FK on `book` and also `tp_to` is a FK and both points to `travel_point.id` maybe here is the problem and I don't see it yet. Anyway, I leave the SQL schema in [this link](http://pastie.org/9410357) because is a bit large, apologies for that but and I provide the same data I've for testing purpose.

What I'm doing wrong?

PS: You can take a look to data on this images I leave and as I said data is shared

[image: book_table]
[image: travel_point]

Comment: Show your table defintions and reduce the data to a minimal example. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And copy content into the question, don't use a link.

Comment: Explain what the query is supposed to return, ie what a row in the query result means, including if necessary what book and travel_point rows mean. How can we know what is a correct query if you don't tell us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` specifically returns a row for every left hand table row; if there's no `ON` match then `NULL` is returned in the columns unique to the right hand table. For your select that returns a row for every `book` row, with  `NULL` addresses when `id` differs from `tp_from` or `tp_to`. If that's not what you want then don't use `LEFT JOIN`. You don't say what you do want so it's hard to advise you otherwise. Presumably just use `JOIN`.

Aside from your `NULL` problem:

Guessing at what your tables mean, your query (after the `LEFT` is dropped) lists first names and corresponding endpoint addresses of round trip bookings. It seems unlikely that a travel point has a from address and a to address. Is there really just a travel point `address`? (But maybe a travel point is a link in an itinerary that knows its preceding/from and following/to address.) It also seems unlikely that you would be listing the same travel point's address twice. For first names and endpoint addresses of bookings you need to join with `travel_point` twice, once for each endpoint. (As in another answer for a different query.)

```
SELECT tpf.address AS address_from, tpt.address AS address_to, bk.firstname
FROM book bk
JOIN travel_point tpf ON bk.tp_from = tpf.id
JOIN travel_point tpt ON bk.tp_to = tpt.id
```

Answer (score 1):

`bk`.`tp_from` = `tp`.`id` AND `bk`.`tp_to` = `tp`.`id`
looks like impossible condition, because it is only satisfied when tp_from = tp_to.

if you want to get both points as separate rows in a result set, change join condition to
`bk`.`tp_from` = `tp`.`id` OR `bk`.`tp_to` = `tp`.`id`

If you want to get 2 travel points related to booking, you have to join travel_point table twice.

```
SELECT *
FROM book AS bk
JOIN travel_point AS tp1 ON `bk`.`tp_from` = `tp1`.`id`
JOIN travel_point AS tp2 ON `bk`.`tp_to` = `tp2`.`id`
```

Comment: 1. The "impossible" situation is reasonably interpreted as a round trip. 2. Assuming the obvious FKs, your query is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM book`.